# $CurrentLink passing down in MathLink SetDelayed functions

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I would like to utilize the MathLink option of having each `Install` of my package result in a linking object which I can use to control when and how certain elements are used in the underlying `C` code.

However, I have difficulties when implementing Mathematica functions on top of the functions which require the `LinkObject`. Of course I need the `SetDelayed` statement due to variable passing etc.

Take for instance the `counter.tm` example:

```
:Evaluate:      BeginPackage[ "counter`"]

:Begin:
:Function:      AddToCounter
:Pattern:       AddToCounter[$CurrentLink, n_Integer]
:Arguments:     {n}
:ArgumentTypes: {Integer}
:ReturnType:    Integer
:End:

:Evaluate:      EndPackage[ ]
```

This works great until I define additional functions, take for instance this additional function (it *is* placed within the `BeginPackage/EndPackage`).

```
:Evaluate:   MyAddToCounter[$CurrentLink,n_Integer] := 
                    Return[AddToCounter[$CurrentLink,n+1]]
```

However, when calling `MyAddToCounter` I only get the function call as a symbol:

```
In[2]:= MyAddToCounter[link,20]
Out[2]:= AddToCounter[$CurrentLink, 21]
```

Why is this?
And how can I preserve the separation of each `LinkObject` to the same package?

Comment: Try defining `MyAddToCounter[link_,n_Integer] := 
AddToCounter[link,n+1]`, or simply `MyAddToCounter[n_Integer] := AddToCounter[$CurrentLink,n+1]`. The `$CurrentLink` variable is a global variable and you don't have to include it in the function's signature. It is likely different when you call the function that when you define it, and so the pattern does not match.

Comment: Brilliant! And I can now see why. The `Install` defines `$CurrentLink` and inserts it whereever specified. However, in cases of `SetDelayed` the function is not evaluated until an explicit call to the function. But at that point the `$CurrentLink` is not valid anymore. Hence we need ordinary variable passing! Thanks a lot! That helped!

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I read your answer but did not check additional comments when I was writing up my answer.. Now your answer is gone and your comment contains everything important.

Comment: @halirutan My answer was wrong. I did not quite remember the mechanics of interation between `Install` and scoping. Usually I just look at the source code generated by `mprep` when I have questions, but had no time today. In any case, one should not answer in comments, and you give a full-fledged answer with explanations, so your answer is *the* answer here. I am actually very happy that you did it since I am quite busy at the moment. I think SE model is pushing us to think too often about the timing and to race to be the first at all costs. I dislike this, we should collaborate more.

Comment: @halirutan Just one thing (being a bit pedantic): since there is no ``Private` `` subsection in the package, usage message is not necessary to export the symbol (I also initially thought it is), as the symbol is already created in the package main context. Of course, having a usage message is a good style anyway.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes of course, because `EndPackage` prepends the current context to `$ContextPath`. I don't like to hurry too when writing an answer because usually I want to try the things carefully. On the other hand it's not that often that I have a question which I really like and then you just feel that you should hurry answering.. It's a pitty.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and @haliruta, i refrained from adding the `usage` statements as they were already in the source. I always include them. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion there are two things to consider. First, you want to evaluate the right hand side of your `MyAddToCounter` during installing your program to ensure that `$CurrentLink` has a value. Second, it is good practive to give your function a `usage` message. Although, this is not required here since you have no `` Private` `` context and the package context is prepended to the `$ContextPath` when `EndPackage` is called. This leaves you with

```
int AddToCounter P(( int));

:Evaluate:      BeginPackage[ "counter`"]

:Begin:
:Function:      AddToCounter
:Pattern:       AddToCounter[$CurrentLink, n_Integer]
:Arguments:     {n}
:ArgumentTypes: {Integer}
:ReturnType:    Integer
:End:

:Evaluate:      AddToCounter::usage = "AddToCounter[ ck, n] adds n to the counter ..."
:Evaluate:      MyAddToCounter::usage = "Pure energy."
:Evaluate:      MyAddToCounter[link_, n_Integer] := AddToCounter[link,n+1]
:Evaluate:      EndPackage[ ]
```

and everything should work fine. Let me make clear what really happens here:

The pattern for `AddToCounter` contains the symbol `$CurrentLink` which gets a different value everytime you `Install` your program. Therefore, when you have n different installations of your MathLink program, you have n different rules in the `DownValues` of `AddToCounter`.

On the other hand `MyAddToCounter` does always have the same pattern and therefore no additional down value rule is added when you install a new instance. Depending on how clever Mathematica is the line `MyAddToCounter[link_, n_Integer] := AddToCounter[link,n+1]` (with an arbitrary complex rhs) is processed every time you install a new instance without any use.

For such occasions I would suggest that you don't pack the code inside the template file. It is completely sufficient to evaluate

```
BeginPackage["counter`"];
MyAddToCounter[link_, n_Integer] := AddToCounter[link, n];
EndPackage[];
```

one time inside your Mathematica session or inside a package which is loaded.

If you **do** have a function which requires to make use of the `$CurrentLink` you cannot simply make a definition like `f[..]:=...$CurrentLink...`. Remember that `SetDelayed` (`:=`) does not evaluate its right side. Therefore, `$CurrentLink` is not evaluate and stays in the definition as symbol. One possible solution is for instance a construct like this

```
With[{link = $CurrentLink},
 MyAddToCounter[link, n_Integer] := AddToCounter[link, n];
]
```

inside the template code.

The conclusion is: If you have an additional function which does not explicitly depend on `$CurrentLink` but only gives it through to a real template-function, you can simply define it inside Mathematica. If it depends explicitly on `$CurrentLink` you need to put in in the template code **and** you need to ensure that it is evaluated correctly during the installation process.

**Compilation of the sample code**

Anyone interested can try this fast by copying `counter.tm` from the examples directory and adapting the paths in the code below. If you are on Windows you may have to use `mprep.exe` in the `Run` call

```
tmfile = "/home/patrick/Documents/notebooks/SE/counter.tm";
{cfile, outfile} = StringReplace[tmfile, start__ ~~ ".tm" :> start ~~ #] & /@  {".c", ""};

Run[$InstallationDirectory <> 
 "/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/"<> $SystemID <>
 "/CompilerAdditions/mprep", tmfile, "-o", cfile]

<< CCompilerDriver`
prog = CreateExecutable[{cfile}, "counter", "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, 
 "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print]

lnk = Install[prog]
MyAddToCounter[lnk, 20]
```

Comment: yes and no. The answer you provide forces the assignment to be `Set` and not `SetDelayed`. I need the `SetDelayed`. Furthermore, the idea of having a global variable within the context of the package and passing the `$CurrentLink` is so that I can load it several times, and have different global variables for each `LinkObject`. This means that `MyAddToCounter[n_Integer] = AddToCounter[$CurrentLink,n+1]` will only work on the latest installed package, and will not let you decide which `LinkObject` that gets incremented. Hence `MyAddToCounter[link_,n_Integer] := AddToCounter[link,n+1]` is needed

Comment: This simple example is not very insightful, but can you explain why you *need* `SetDelayed`? Have you really understood what does (not) happen with the `DownValues` of `MyAddCounter` when you use the pattern `MyAddToCounter[link_,n_]`? And finally, that you need the link name on the left hand side of your function def in order to distinguish several installs  is already explained under the first code box.

Comment: probably I have no idea why, would you mind we take it to a chat?

Comment: @zeroth, I'm chattable now.

Comment: I have sevaral calls within the actual function that I call, so I would like to have it executed each time instead of the usual `Set`. It involves a function: `MyReadFile[link_,fname_String, OptionsPattern[{...}]] := Module[{tmp},Switch[tmp = OptionValue[...],...];Return[templateMyReadFile[fname]];` if that makes it more clear why I need `SetDelayed`?

Comment: join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5970/zeroth-halirutan